# Stop last column of multicolumn table from leaving right side of page

Tags: tables, multicolumn

The code below leads to this table:

[image]

where the right hand side goes off the page but the last column of data is not displayed. The table should fit on the page -- it is not too wide, except that the right column is inexplicably extended off of the page. For instance, the caption is wider than where the last column of data should be, and that caption easily fits in the page. What am I missing?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Site and structural characterization data for the samples in this study.}
  \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Sample}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Si/Sn \\Ratio \\ (AAS)$^a$\\}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Si/Sn\\ Ratio \\ (EDS)$^b$}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering V\textsubscript{ads, micro}\\(cm$^3$ g\textsuperscript{-1})}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering DRUV \\Band \\ Center\\ (nm)$^e$}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering DRUV\\ Edge \\Energy\\ (eV)$^e$} \\\hline
 Sn-CHA-F-60&59&65&0.16$^c$&219&4.33\\
Sn-CHA-F-70&70&65&0.15$^c$&223&4.12\\
Sn-Beta-F-116&116&122&0.23$^d$&222&4.23\\
 Sn-xerogel&110&130&0.02$^c$&245&4.37\\
Si-CHA-F&n.m.*&n.m.*&0.23$^c$&n.m.*&n.m.*\\\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^a$Bulk composition determined by atomic absorption spectroscopy (AAS).} \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^b$Composition determined by energy dispersive X-ray spectroscopy (EDS).} \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^c$Micropore volume determined from Ar adsorption isotherms (87 K). } \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^d$Micropore volume determined from N$_2$ adsorption isotherms (77 K). } \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^e$Diffuse reflectance UV-Vis spectra (band center at maximum F(R) intensity) and Tauc plots for samples after dehydration at 523 K (Section \ref{sec: chas5}). } \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{*n. m., not measured} \\
\end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \label{ta: cd3cn1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (MWE).

Comment: @TeXnician  I disagree with closing this question.  The problem here is different.  It's not a matter of the table being too wide, but of columns dropping out if the table notes are too wide.  I don't see a solution in the referenced answer that addresses this.

Comment: @JPi The table notes are too wide because they are written in a `\multicolumn` with an `l` column, so using a `p` column instead there would help, and that must be described in the suggested dupe. (Granted, a better solution would make the last `multicolumns` as wide as the table without trial and error to find a width, but I think there has been a question about that before.)

Comment: Doesn't explain the dropped last column.....

Answer (score 2):

Your table notes were too long; split them and all is well.  Also, use `\centering` in tables and figures.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Site and structural characterization data for the samples in this study.}
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Sample}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Si/Sn \\Ratio \\ (AAS)$^a$\\}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Si/Sn\\ Ratio \\ (EDS)$^b$}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering V\textsubscript{ads, micro}\\(cm$^3$ g\textsuperscript{-1})}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering DRUV \\Band \\ Center\\ (nm)$^e$}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering DRUV\\ Edge \\Energy\\ (eV)$^e$} \\\hline
 Sn-CHA-F-60&59&65&0.16$^c$&219&4.33\\
Sn-CHA-F-70&70&65&0.15$^c$&223&4.12\\
Sn-Beta-F-116&116&122&0.23$^d$&222&4.23\\
 Sn-xerogel&110&130&0.02$^c$&245&4.37\\
Si-CHA-F&n.m.*&n.m.*&0.23$^c$&n.m.*&n.m.*\\\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^a$Bulk composition determined by atomic absorption spectroscopy (AAS).} \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^b$Composition determined by energy dispersive X-ray spectroscopy (EDS).} \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^c$Micropore volume determined from Ar adsorption isotherms (87 K). } \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^d$Micropore volume determined from N$_2$ adsorption isotherms (77 K). } \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{$^e$Diffuse reflectance UV-Vis spectra (band center at maximum F(R) intensity)}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\hspace{3ex} and Tauc plots for samples after dehydration at 523 K (Section \ref{sec: chas5}). } \\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{*n. m., not measured} \\
\end{tabular}
  \label{ta: cd3cn1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't assure that the tabular material will actually fit inside the width of the textblock. Better to use either a `tabularx` or a `tabular*` environment.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you (a) use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, (b) use the machinery of the `threeparttable` -- especially the `\tnote` macros and the `tablenotes` environment, and (c) the `\si` and `\SI` macros of the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered "X" columns    
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit} % italic footnote markers

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Site and structural characterization data for the samples in this study.} 
\label{ta:cd3cn1}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l CCCCC @{}}
\toprule 
Sample
& Si/Sn Ratio  (AAS)\tnote{a}
& Si/Sn Ratio  (EDS)\tnote{b}
& V\textsubscript{ads,micro} (\si{\centi\meter\cubed} \si{\gram\tothe{-1}})
& DRUV Band Center (\si{\nano\meter})\tnote{e}
& DRUV Edge Energy (\si{\electronvolt})\tnote{e} \\
\midrule
Sn-CHA-F-60   & 59  & 65  &0.16\tnote{c} &219  &4.33\\
Sn-CHA-F-70   & 70  & 65  &0.15\tnote{c} &223  &4.12\\
Sn-Beta-F-116 &116  &122  &0.23\tnote{d} &222  &4.23\\
Sn-xerogel    &110  &130  &0.02\tnote{c} &245  &4.37\\
Si-CHA-F      &n.m.*&n.m.*&0.23\tnote{c} &n.m.*&n.m.*\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Bulk composition determined by atomic absorption spectroscopy (AAS).
\item[b] Composition determined by energy dispersive X-ray spectroscopy (EDS).
\item[c] Micropore volume determined from Ar adsorption isotherms 
         (\SI{87}{\kelvin}). 
\item[d] Micropore volume determined from N\textsubscript{2} adsorption 
         isotherms (\SI{77}{\kelvin}). 
\item[e] Diffuse reflectance UV-Vis spectra (band center at maximum F(R) 
         intensity) and Tauc plots for samples after dehydration at 
         \SI{523}{\kelvin} (Section \ref{sec:chas5}). 
\end{tablenotes}
n.m.* not measured
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```